# All combinations of list of lists fulfilling specific conditions

Tags: python

I am looking to get all possible combinations of a list of lists, but with a few specific conditions.
The conditions that have to be fulfilled:

1. I assume all sub-lists in the input list have the same length `N`
2. I can only choose a specific amount per column
3. Output should contain only lists of size `N`
4. I can only choose one value (column) per row

Example:

```
# Columns 0 1 2
lst  =  [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

choose = [2,1,0] # here choose only two from first column and one from middle column
```

To help track columns I modify the input list and encapsulate each item in an object (value, column_index).

```
>> lst = encapsulate(lst)
[[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)],
 [(4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2)],
 [(7, 0), (8, 1), (9, 2)]]
>> combine(lst, choose)
[[(1, 0), (4, 0), (8, 1)],
 [(1, 0), (5, 1), (7, 0)],
 [(2, 1), (4, 0), (7, 0)]]
```

I have a solution that works for smaller lists, but my goal is to run this on a 20x12 matrix. Is there any feasible way to solve this?

My current solution:

```
class Encapsulation:
    def __init__(self, value, column_index):
        self.value = value
        self.column_index = column_index

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%d, %d)" % (self.value, self.column_index)


def combine(L, choose):
    combinations = []

    choose_n = len(choose)

    def _combine(terms, accum):
        last = (len(terms) == 1)
        n = len(terms[0])
        for i in range(n):
            item = accum + [terms[0][i]]
            if last:
                if can_choose(item, choose, choose_n):
                    combinations.append(item)
            else:
                if can_choose(item, choose, choose_n):
                    _combine(terms[1:], item)

    _combine(L, [])
    return combinations

def encapsulate(lst):
    outlist = []
    for j in range(0, len(lst)):
        new_l = []
        for i in range(0, len(lst[j])):
            new_l.append(Encapsulation(lst[j][i], i))
        outlist.append(new_l)
    return outlist

def can_choose(l, _choose, n):
    counts = [0]*n

    for _item in l:
        counts[_item.column_index] += 1
        if counts[_item.column_index] > _choose[_item.column_index]:
            return False

    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]]

    choose = [2,1,0]

    lst = encapsulate(lst)
    assert(sum(choose) == len(lst) and len(choose) == len(lst[0]))
    combinations = combine(lst, choose)
    print(combinations)
```

## EDIT 1:

I managed to make a slightly faster implementation. But still not feasible for large matrices.

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    "Alternative fast implementation of product for python < 2.6"
    choose = kwds.get('choose', [])
    choose_n = len(choose)

    def cycle(values, uplevel):
        for prefix in uplevel:       # cycle through all upper levels
            counts = [0]*choose_n

            for _item in prefix:
                counts[_item.column_index] += 1

            for current in values:   # restart iteration of current level
                i = current.column_index
                if counts[i]+1 <= choose[i]:
                    yield prefix + (current,)

    stack = iter(((),))
    for level in tuple(map(tuple, args)):
        stack = cycle(level, stack)  # build stack of iterators
    return stack
```

Used like this

```
lst  =  [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

choose = [2,1,0]
product(*lst, choose=choose)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind choosing 2 elements from 3 in the first column? That is to say, it doesn't seem like you're choosing at random? It would be helpful if you describe.

Comment: I have boiled it down to a minimal example, but the original issue is that I have a list of people (rows) with skills (columns). Each person has a skill level in each skill. I want to choose, for instance, 2 people the first skill, and one with the middle skill. Ultimately I am looking to find the best combination to maximum the sum of skill level if I choose a predetermined set of persons per skill.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `itertools` that will generate the possible outputs, without the possible permutations of each solution. If you want the permutations as well, just generate all permutations of each of these outputs.

I start by building the columns, then a generator of all possible combinations of the requested number of values from each column. Finally, we make the product of these combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain

lst  =  [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

choose = [2,1,0]


columns = list(zip(*lst))
# [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]

if sum(choose) != len(columns[0]):
    raise ValueError(f'You must choose {len(columns[0])} values')

combinations = [combinations(columns[index], r=number) for index, number in enumerate(choose)]

for comb in product(*combinations):
    out = list(chain.from_iterable(comb))
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 8]
[1, 7, 2]
[1, 7, 5]
[1, 7, 8]
[4, 7, 2]
[4, 7, 5]
[4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can only choose one value per row. So, for instance, your first result is not valid since it contains both 1 and 2 from the first row.

Comment: Yeah I realize that. I have spent quite some time on this by now that I didn't notice it wasn't specific enough. Thanks for the help though. Even if your solution returns a much much bigger output list, it seems to run much faster than my solution. If I can reduce it to only consider one column per row, then perhaps the (20 Rows X 12 Columns) matrix can be handled. Otherwise the number of combinations is just too big.